# Descarga de archivos con powershell Start-BitsTransfer

Tags: powershell

Hola tengo una lista de 15 mil archivos que puedo descargar, pero demora mucho, me he planteado crear un script en `PowerShell` pero no logro hacerlo funciona.

```
$srcfile = "cardlist.txt"
$data = Get-Content $srcfile
foreach($url in $data){
    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($url)
    $file = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd.Path, $filename)
    Start-BitsTransfer $url -Destination $file -Asynchronous
    Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer
}
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer leer la lista de urls desde un txt e intentar descargarlas de forma asyncrona con `Start-BitsTransfer` utiliando `Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer` para monitorear el proceso ... pero simplemente comienza la ejecucion pero no veo donde van a dar las imagenes estoy usando `PowerShell ISE`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Me gustaría responder en forma de comentario pero me falta reputación.

De lo que indicas:

> pero simplemente comienza la ejecucion pero no veo donde van a dar las imagenes

Entiendo que el script te esta funcionado pero no sabes donde esta guardando lo que descarga, la respuesta es en C:\Users\wnune ten en cuenta que aunque el script esta en otra carpeta, no se descargaran los archivos en la misma ruta del script, ya que lo estas ejecutando parado sobre la ruta C:\Users\wnune, por general powershell te indica la ruta sobre la que estas parado, si no estas seguro también te lo dice con el comando `pwd`, si por otro lado quieres estar sobre otra ruta y que se descargue en otro lugar puedes poner `cd C:\rutadeseada` ya sea dirctamente en la powershell antes de correr el script, o al inicio del script.

Comment: Listo ya lo he resuelto

Answer (score 0):

He mejorado el script y lo he resuelto, implementando `Start-BitsTransfer`, `Get-BitsTransfer`  y `Complete-BitsTransfer`:

```
$srcfile = "cardlist.txt" // donde se encuentra el archivo lista url
$data = Get-Content $srcfile
foreach($url in $data){
    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($url)
    $file = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("Imágenes", $filename) // lugar a donde se va a guardar cada temporal
    Start-BitsTransfer $url -Destination $file -Asynchronous
}

# Monitorear la descarga de los archivos
while ((Get-BitsTransfer | Where-Object {$_.JobState -eq "Transferring"})){
    Get-BitsTransfer | Where-Object {$_.JobState -eq "Transferring"} | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Descargando archivo $($_.FileName) al $($_.Destination)"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# Completar la descarga de los archivos
Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer // ejecuta el completar de todas las descargas.
```