# Error al implementar Start-BitsTransfer, Get-BitsTransfer y Complete-BitsTransfer en descarga masiva

Tags: powershell

he intentado dar respuesta a mi propia pregunta en este link:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/575253/16419

Y aunque funciona con pocos archivos al intentar descargar una cantidad masiva de archivo recibo el siguiente error:

> Complete-BitsTransfer : El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo
> especificado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070002) En línea: 1 Carácter:
> 20
>
> - Get-BitsTransfer | Complete-BitsTransfer
> - ```
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Complete-BitsTransfer], FileNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.Compl
>     eteBitsTransferCommand

Al investigar sobre el tema, pareciera que fuece un error o corrupcion de la descarga, pero no se como se pueda resolver esto, si alguien conoce del tema que pueda apoyar mi respuesta se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

para una solucion eficas y eficiente; he tenido que actualizar PowerShell a la version 7.3; adicional implementar `ForEach-Object -parallel` y el siquiente codigo:

```
$srcfile = "cardlist.txt" //colocar el path de la lista de recursos
$urls = Get-Content $srcfile

$urls | ForEach-Object -parallel {
  $url = $_
    try {
        $filename = Split-Path $url -Leaf
        $destination = "C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Escritorio\imagenes\$filename" //colocar el path deseado
        $job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $destination -Asynchronous
        while (($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Transferring" -or ($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState -eq "Connecting")
        { 
            Start-Sleep -m 250
        }
    
        Switch(($job | Get-BitsTransfer).JobState)
        {
            "Transferred" {
                Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $job
            }
            "Error" {
                $job | Format-List
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Error "There was an error downloading $url : $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

para llegar a esta conclusion y entender que estaba mal y que debia hacer he recurrido a la ayuda de ChatGPT.